# Micro services Service discovery using Eureka and traefik with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka, traefik

Traefik for dummies question. I am trying to setup spring cloud micro services with docker compose using traefik as reverse proxy.

My aim is micro services should talk to each other via service name (ex: service-registry-app) and traefik should resolve it to ip address. Once this works in local box, I want to extend it to run on AWS ECS.

I have created ana_network using

```
docker network create ana_network
```

### traefik configuration:

File: docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - ana_network
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml

networks:
  ana_network:
    driver: bridge
```

### micro services configuration:

File: docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  service-registry:
    image: sqshq/piggymetrics-registry
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    expose:
      - "8761"
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=service-registry-app"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:service-registry-app.example.com"
    environment:
      CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD: $CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD    
  config-server:
    image: sqshq/piggymetrics-config
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    expose:
      - "8888"
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
    environment:
       EUREKA_HOST: service-registry-app.example.com
       EUREKA_PORT: 8761
       CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD: $CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD

    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=config-server-app"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:config-server-app.example.com"    
networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: ana_network
```

I can access service registry app using curl

```
curl -H Host:service-registry-app.example.com http://172.21.0.2:8761
```

But config server and api gateway unable to access service registry with above configuration with docker compose and traefik.

What changes I need to do in order make all micro services to be able discover each other and How to extend it to make it work on ECS?

Edit1:

Corrected indentation to move networks section from services to networks, it was a typo.

I am newbie into containers and distributed systems hence I might be asking some naive obvious questions hence it would be great if any traefik for dummies would be very helpful.

Following are the 2 problems I am facing currently,

1) container to container communication - Example, How container 2 (config server in this example) should communicate with container 1 (service-registry), by service name (like service-registry) or any other way and How to access these containers from external world (in this case service registry)?

2) Extending it to make it work in ECS, hence each will have its own task definition and run as a service inside ECS cluster - in this scenario how containers should communicate with each other using traefik?

Comment: What's the web section at the end of your second compose file trying to do? Looks like you wanted to define a network but defined a service instead.

Comment: Thank you pointing out. It was typo while typing it here. Still facing same issue, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

Your container to container networking appears to be broken in multiple places. With your traefik compose file, you define a network but don't mark it as external, so that compose will create a `${project}_ana_network` network that other projects won't see. Fix that by marking it as external with:

```
networks:
  ana_network:
    external:
      name: ana_network
```

In your second compose file, you define a web service which looks like you're trying to define a web network, and that appears to be caused by indenting "networks" incorrectly. Honestly, I don't know how that would even run as written since the "web" network wouldn't exist for your other services to use.

For traefik integration, I prefer to not define the backend name, and to specify the network name and port, so traefik knows how to connect to the container in case you ever define multiple networks or ports on a container.

The result would look like:

```
version: '2'

services:
  service-registry:
    image: sqshq/piggymetrics-registry
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    expose:
      - "8761"
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:service-registry-app.example.com"
      - "traefik.docker.network=ana_network"
      - "traefik.port=8761"
    environment:
      CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD: $CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD    
  config-server:
    image: sqshq/piggymetrics-config
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    expose:
      - "8888"
    depends_on:
      - service-registry
    environment:
       EUREKA_HOST: service-registry-app.example.com
       EUREKA_PORT: 8761
       CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD: $CONFIG_SERVICE_PASSWORD

    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=config-server-app"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:config-server-app.example.com"    

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: ana_network
```

Lastly, I haven't setup a Eureka install, but if you want containers to talk directly over the container network, I'd recommend using:

```
EUREKA_HOST: service-registry
```

Specifying the address listed with traefik will send the request out of docker to come back in through traefik, adding unnecessary hops.

If you need to have EUREKA_HOST set to the external name but still want to use container to container networking, then you can configure a network alias:

```
services:
  service-registry:
    ...
    networks:
      web:
        aliases:
        - "service-registry-app.example.com"
```

Comment: Corrected indentation and update question with more details. Still unable to access another container service, please help.

Comment: The answer above recommended more than that typo correction.